# Alert when current location is near marker android map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an app for android that uses google map. its like a navigation app that updates the location on screen while in motion. I have placed multiple markers on the map and for each marker there is a radius of 125. When the current location intersects with the marker radius I get a warning message. This is done by looping through all markers and check if the current location intersect with the radius of any of the markers at the OnLocationChangedMethod() . it works well if you have couple of markers but I have more than 30 markers. By the time it takes to loop through all markers and report if there is an intersection , current location would have passed the marker. so it takes longer time and its not very efficient.

I hope someone can help for a better approach on how to do that. I have read couple of solutions that suggest taking the map bounds and find the visible marker. but this also iterate through all marker and it would take the same time as my solution.

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Thanks,

Abdullah

Comment: why not you save the marker locations in your database and compare with user location in each 45 seconds through your service..

Comment: The markers are actually stored on a server database. at first initialisation of the app , the markers gets downloaded and saved locally in SQLite database. 45 seconds it too long. the marker radius is 250 meter. it would take on average 25 seconds to get passed the marker. the times is not issue. the process of checking if there is an intersection actually takes the time based on number of markers stored in the database.  I dont know if there is a solution that let the markers act like a radar not the current location marker.

Comment: did you find any solution?? if any could you share any repository i am working on my university project and i need similar functionality! it will help me a lot! thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you would be better suited for [Geofencing](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) because it is basically what you are trying to do. No need for all these different services and such when there is something already built in

Comment: After a lot of of integration with my code and google map. it works really well. Thank you very much.  A quick question. is there a limit for the number Geofence points that you add or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Use two services.  One to get the current location and another to calculate the distances.

Comment: Sorry didn't have enough time to complete my reply.  Use two services.  One service that broadcasts the Location and another service that calculates the proximity to each point.  This way, theoretically anyway and about the best one can do under the circumstances, the proximity calculation will not delay the location  broadcast.